# I keep getting the error : TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len() when passing a list of float values

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I’m trying to run a function Stat_test_wrap that takes in a DataFrame, a column name, and a list of thresholds as arguments. However, when I call the function with the following arguments:

```
Tsel = 'T1'
Thres = [3.7, 9.5, 5.1, 9.9]
pmat_T1 = Stat_test_wrap(df, Tsel, Thres)
```

I get the following error:

```
      1 Tsel = 'T1'
      2 Thres = [3.7, 9.5, 5.1, 9.9]
----> 3 pmat_T1 = Stat_test_wrap(df, Tsel, Thres)
      4 pmat_T1.to_csv("T1.csv", index=False)
      5 

/tmp/ipykernel_72926/2566377290.py in Stat_test_wrap(data, Tsel, Thres)
     84 
     85 def Stat_test_wrap(data, Tsel, Thres):
---> 86     pct20 = Stat_test(data, Tsel, Thres[0])
     87     pct80 = Stat_test(data, Tsel, Thres[1])
     88     TharaL = Stat_test(data, Tsel, Thres[2])

/tmp/ipykernel_72926/2566377290.py in Stat_test(data, Tsel, thres)
      2     pvalues = []
      3 
----> 4     if len(thres) == 2:
      5         data['cat'] = (data[Tsel] >= thres[0]) & (data[Tsel] <= thres[1])
      6     else:

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

The error seems to be occurring in the Stat_test function, which is called by Stat_test_wrap. Here’s the relevant code:

```
def Stat_test(data, Tsel, thres):
    pvalues = []
    
    if len(thres) == 2:
        data['cat'] = (data[Tsel] >= thres[0]) & (data[Tsel] <= thres[1])
    else:
        data['cat'] = (data[Tsel] >= thres)

    data['cat'] = data['cat'].astype('category')
    
    
    # sleep quality
    con1 = pd.crosstab(data['Sleep'], data['cat'])
    _, m = fisher_exact(con1)
    pvalues.append(m)

    _, m1 = wilcoxon(data['Sleep Count'], data['cat'], alternative='two-sided')
    pvalues.append(m1)

    _, m1 = wilcoxon(data['hf Sleep Score'], data['cat'], alternative='two-sided')
    pvalues.append(m1)

    # Energy
    con1 = pd.crosstab(data['Energy'], data['cat'])
    _, m = fisher_exact(con1)
    pvalues.append(m)

    _, m1 = wilcoxon(data['Energy Count'], data['cat'], alternative='two-sided')
    pvalues.append(m1)

    _, m1 = wilcoxon(data['hf Energy Score'], data['cat'], alternative='two-sided')
    pvalues.append(m1)

    # Bowel issue
    con1 = pd.crosstab(data['Bowel Issues'], data['cat'])
    _, m = fisher_exact(con1)
    pvalues.append(m)

    # Feelings
    con1 = pd.crosstab(data['FeelingsB'], data['cat'])
    _, m = fisher_exact(con1)
    pvalues.append(m)

    # Movement group
    con1 = pd.crosstab(data['Movement Quality'], data['cat'])
    _, m = fisher_exact(con1)
    pvalues.append(m)

    # Rest Quality RA1-4 and RA1-5 are positive group
    con1 = pd.crosstab(data['Rest Quality'], data['cat'])
    _, m = fisher_exact(con1)
    pvalues.append(m)

    # social connection
    con1 = pd.crosstab(data['Social Connection'], data['cat'])
    _, m = fisher_exact(con1)
    pvalues.append(m)

    # social frequency
    con1 = pd.crosstab(data['Social frequency'], data['cat'])
    _, m = fisher_exact(con1)
    pvalues.append(m)

    # virtual RL
    con1 = pd.crosstab(data['Virtual/RL'], data['cat'])
    _, m = fisher_exact(con1)
    pvalues.append(m)

    # Time outdoor
    con1 = pd.crosstab(data['Time outdoors'], data['cat'])
    _, m = fisher_exact(con1)
    pvalues.append(m)

    # outdoor location
    con1 = pd.crosstab(data['Buildings vs Nature'], data['cat'])
    _, m = fisher_exact(con1)
    pvalues.append(m)

    # stress level
    _, m1 = wilcoxon(data['Stress level'], data['cat'], alternative='two-sided')
    pvalues.append(m1)

    return pvalues

def Stat_test_wrap(data, Tsel, Thres):
    pct20 = Stat_test(data, Tsel, Thres[0])
    pct80 = Stat_test(data, Tsel, Thres[1])
    TharaL = Stat_test(data, Tsel, Thres[2])
    TharaH = Stat_test(data, Tsel, Thres[3])
    Med = Stat_test(data, Tsel, data[Tsel].median())
    pct20_80 = Stat_test(data, Tsel, Thres[:2])
    TharaL_H = Stat_test(data, Tsel, Thres[2:4])

    pmat = pd.DataFrame([pct20, pct80, TharaL, TharaH, Med, pct20_80, TharaL_H])
    cols = ["Sleep","Sleep Count","hf Sleep Score","Energy","Energy Count","hf Energy Score","Bowel Issues","FeelingsB",
           "Movement Quality","Rest Quality","Social Connection","Social frequency","Virtual\RL","Time outdoors",
            "Buildings vs Nature","Stress level"]
    pmat.columns = cols

    return pmat
```

I do not have any missing values in my dataframe.
Can anyone help me understand why I’m getting this error and how to fix it?

Comment: (1) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question. (2) What is `Stat_test_wrap`?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I have added the complete code and the full traceback of the error

Comment: `Stat_test_wrap` calls `Stat_test` with `thres[0]` (and following), which is just a float, as `thres` argument for `Stat_test` which in turn tries to get the `len` of the float.

Comment: The `Stat_test()` function expects the `thres` argument to be a list.  But when you call it, you're passing a single float, not a list, as that argument.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thank you! I modified the if statement to check for a float value instead of len. It is working now